# why i^=j^=i^=j isn't equal to *i^=*j^=*i^=*j

Tags: javascript, c, pointers, logical-operators

In C, when there are variables (assume both as `int`) `i` less than `j`, we can use the equation

```
i^=j^=i^=j
```

to exchange the value of the two variables. For example, let `int i = 3`, `j = 5`; after computed `i^=j^=i^=j`, I have `i = 5`, `j = 3`.

However, if I use two int pointers to re-do this, with `*i^=*j^=*i^=*j`, using the example above, what I have will be `i = 0` and `j = 3`.

---

**In C**

### 1

```
    int i=3, j=5;
    i^=j^=i^=j; // after this i = 5, j=3
```

### 2

```
    int i = 3, j= 5;
    int *pi = &i, *pj = &j;
    *pi^=*pj^=*pi^=*pj; // after this, $pi = 0, *pj = 5
```

**In JavaScript**

```
    var i=3, j=5;
    i^=j^=i^=j; // after this, i = 0, j= 3
```

***the result in JavaScript makes this more interesting to me***

my sample code , on ubuntu server 11.0 & gcc

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int i=7, j=9;
        int *pi=&i, *pj=&j;
        i^=j^=i^=j;
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
        i=7, j=9;
        *pi^=*pj^=*pi^=*pj
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", *pi, *pj);
    }
```

---

## undefined behavior in c

Will the undefined behavior in c be the real reason leads to this question?

#### 1

code compiled use ***visual studio 2005 on windows 7*** produce the expected result ( Output i = 7, j = 9 twice.)

#### 2

code compiled use ***gcc on ubuntu*** ( **gcc test.c** ) produce the unexpected result ( Output i = 7, j = 9  then i = 0, j = 9 )

#### 3

code compiled use ***gcc on ubuntu*** ( **gcc -O test.c** ) produce the expected result ( Output i = 7,j = 9 twice. )

Comment: Same idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: Does your code even compile? You are trying to dereference an `int`.

Comment: Why bother?! `int temp = i; i = j; j = temp;` works every time.

Comment: Implement that simply is a better way also. But, I just curious about what was happened.

Comment: Regarding your edit: undefined behavior certainly can lead to the behavior you're seeing, since undefined behavior means that anything can happen (there is no 'expected' behavior for the compiler).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i^=j^=i^=j` is undefined behavior in C.

You are violating sequence points rules by modifying `i` two times between two sequence points.

It means the implementation is free to assign any value or even make your program crash.

For the same reason, `*i^=*j^=*i^=*j` is also undefined behavior.

> (C99, 6.5p2) "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int i=7, j=9;
        int *pi=&i, *pj=&j;
        i^=j^=i^=j;
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
        i=7, j=9;
        *pi^=*pj^=*pi^=*pj;
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", *pi, *pj);

        return 0;
    }
```

If you try to compile it you will see a `warning: unsequenced modification` for the first line. As @ouath said it's not well-defined. According to the [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) the assignment-expressions work in a [read-modify-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-modify-write) fashion. This operation isn't atomic on all the CPU architectures. You can read more about the warning [here](http://www.bionoren.com/blog/2013/07/unsequenced-modification-and-access/).

It's interesting to see that for `*pi^=*pj^=*pi^=*pj;` there is no warning in my LLVM compiler.

Comment: Hi, This is my first time to learn how to submit a question and eventually encountered some problem with the markdown editor. The question was corrected, look forward for you attention.

Comment: See my answer, `*pi^=*pj^=*pi^=*pj` is undefined behavior in C. You cannot expect any reliable behavior.

Comment: Which IDE was the c code that you posted on codepad.org compiled on? visual studio c/c++ under Windows Or gcc/g++ under linux ? It seems that code compiled on widows vs2005 c++ produce the right result twice( which expected i = 9, j = 7 ), but gcc on linux seems not.

Comment: gcc 4.1.2 
flags: -O -fmessage-length=0 -fno-merge-constants -fstrict-aliasing -fstack-protector-all

Comment: After test, I find that gcc -O  let the program compiled produce the expected result. I will wonder what 'gcc -O' had done to the binary code  ? And, could you give me some idea about how and why to use gcc -O?

Comment: you can use -S to see the assembly, let me know what you are coming up with.... you should compile with and without -O and tkdiff or diff the two assembly files

Answer (score 3):

As for the 'more interesting' aspect added by the Javascript result:

While the expression is undefined in C [as explained in ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332454/12711), it is well-defined in Javascript. However the rules for how the expression is evaluated in Javascript might not be what you expect.

The ECMAscript spec says that a compound assignment operator is evaluated like so (ECMA-262 11.13.2):

> The production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression `@=`
>   AssignmentExpression,where `@` represents one of the operators
>   indicated above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 3. Evaluate AssignmentExpression.
> 4. Call GetValue(Result(3)).
> 5. Apply operator @ to Result(2) and Result(4).
> 6. Call PutValue(Result(1), Result(5)).
> 7. Return Result(5).

So the expression `i ^= j ^= i ^= j` would be evaluated in the following steps:

```
i = (3 ^ (j ^= i ^= j))

i = (3 ^ (j = (5 ^ i ^= j)))

i = (3 ^ (j = (5 ^ (i = 3 ^ j)))))

i = (3 ^ (j = (5 ^ (i = 3 ^ 5)))))

i = (3 ^ (j = (5 ^ (i = 6)))))

i = (3 ^ (j = (5 ^ 6))))

i = (3 ^ (j = 3))   // j is set to 3

i = (3 ^ 3)

i = 0               // i is set to 0
```

Yet another reason to avoid the trick of using an xor operation to swap values.